# Get attribute values from all elements

Tags: java, jsoup

Code:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("things.com").get();

    Elements jpgs = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
    String links = jpgs.attr("src"); 

    System.out.print("all: " + jpgs);
    System.out.print("src: " + links);
```

Output:

```
all:
<img alt="Apple" src="apple.jpg">
<img alt="Cat" src="cat.jpg">
<img alt="Boat" src="boat.jpg">

src: apple.jpg
```

Jsoup gave the attribute value for first element. How can I get the others (cat.jpg and boat.jpg)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through `links` and get it from each one via [`Element#attr`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr-java.lang.String-boolean-), since [`Elements#attr`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#attr-java.lang.String-) (note the `s`) says:

> Get an attribute value from **the first matched element that has the attribute**.

*(My emphasis.)*

So for instance:

```
for (Element e : jpgs) {
    // use e.attr("src") here
}
```

<s>Using Java 8's [new `Stream` stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), you can probably get a `List<String>` of them if you like:</s>

```
List<String> links = jpgs.stream<Element>()
                             .map(element -> element.attr("src"))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...but my Java 8 streams-fu is **very** weak, so that may not be quite right. Yeah, that isn't right. But that's the general idea.

The boring old-fashioned way is:

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(links.size());
for (Element e : jpgs) {
    srcs.add(e.attr("src"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Crowder

Answer (score 1):

`Elements#attr` will only return the first match.

---

### [`Elements#attr` Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.2/org/jsoup/select/Elements.java#Elements.attr%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public String attr(String attributeKey) {
    for (Element element : this) {
        if (element.hasAttr(attributeKey))
             return element.attr(attributeKey);
        }
    return "";
}
```

---

### Solution

To obtain the result you want, you should loop over your `Elements`

```
for (Element e : jpgs) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
}
```